# Physics related integrals and sums. Black Body Radiation.

Tags: integration, summation, physics

How were these calculated?
$$\langle E\rangle = \frac{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty Ee^{-E/kT}{\rm d}E}{\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-E/kT}{\rm d}E}=kT$$
$$ \langle E\rangle = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nh\nu e^{-nh\nu/kT}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nh\nu/kT}}=\frac{\displaystyle h\nu}{\displaystyle e^{h\nu/kT}-1}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{8\pi \nu^2}{c^3}.\frac{\displaystyle h\nu}{\displaystyle e^{h\nu/kT}-1}{\rm d}\nu=\frac 4c\sigma T^4$$
$$\sigma:=\frac{2\pi^5k^4}{15h^3c^2}$$

---

I did the first one using integration by parts, numerator is $(kT)^2$ and denominator $(kT)$ using $\int u{\rm d}v=uv-\int v{\rm d}u$.
Also I know $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x=\frac1{1-x},|x|<1$

Comment: Just to be sure, is it $-E/(kT)$ or $-(E/k)T$ that $e$ is raised to?

Comment: @mickep former.

Comment: I think you want to integrate with respect to $E$.

Comment: @RonGordon actually yes

Comment: What are your own thoughts? The first two can be done rather easily integrating by parts and summing geometric series (and a differentiated version of it). For the last one, there must be a mistake. The $c^{-3}$ in the left-hand side just goes through and must be a $c^{-3}$ in the right-hand side as well.

Comment: The third one doesn't need integrating -- just substitute $s=h\nu/kT$ and note that $T^4$ can be pulled out of the integral and the rest is a constant; then it's just a matter of convention that part of this constant is denoted by $\sigma$.

Comment: @mickep: No, $c^{-2}$ is absorbed into $\sigma$, the [Stefan–Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant).

Comment: @joriki That was actually part of my point (that we needed more information). This question has been incomplete and wrong several times now... The number of edits is slowly growing to infinity...

Comment: @mickep: I share your frustration; I was merely objecting to "there must be a mistake".

Comment: for the second integral see here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function
in the chapter containing mellin transform